# Confused about data model in Hartl's railstutorial in Chapter 12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

So in chapter 12 or Hartl's Railstutorial, we're building the ability for users to follow one another's "twitter" feeds. This is modeled as users forming relationships and we create a relationship model with a table that has a follower_id and a followed_id. Also in the model, we associate it with the user model as follows:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
end
```

We also associate the user model with the relationship model as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :active_relationships,  class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships,  source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
```

I'm confused as to why we need to have has_many :following in the user model. It says in the tutorial that following someone is an active relationship, so why do we need to say users have many active relationships, and users are also following many (which is an active relationship). What exactly is has_many :following doing that has_many :active_relationships cannot do?

Also my second question is why the belongs_to is split into follower and followed, instead of just user. What do we gain by using two belongs_to instead of just one on the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a way to access the `Users` that are either following or being followed by a particular user instead of the relationships.

If you just had `@user.active_relationships` that would return back the relationships in the join table. But with `@user.following` you get an association array of `User` objects.

And as for your second question, a relationship between two users takes 2 objects not one, and would be pointless to have just a single `belongs_to :user`.

[Ruby on Rails Guides - Associations | Has many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: Thanks, perfect explaination